# How does the text formatting or styling defined by Open Office XML get rendered on the screen?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, libreoffice, openoffice, xml

My understanding of the Office Open XML standard used in word processing is, that it's a set of rules for how to display an office document. So documents look the same on all devices and multiple software e.g. Word, OpenOffice or LibreOffice. But afaik the Open XML standard doesn't actually render anything on the screen. So how does the text, written in for example Word with all it's formatting, actually get rendered on screen?
Does Word / LibreOffice call the native System APIs in the background?

Maybe this has been answered somewhere already but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Are you asking about Office Open XML, the Microsoft format? To start with, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML, including the disambiguation notes at the top. Also your question sounds a bit idealistic; `.docx` will never look the same in software such as LibreOffice as it does in MS Word. Close, yes, but not the same, because the platforms do things differently in fundamental ways. For a format that "look[s] the same on all devices and multiple software," use PDF.

Comment: Word documents change appearance from device to device routinely. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TextReflow.htm http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/sharing/willmyformatchange.html Among other things, Word uses the printer driver in rendering the document on the screen.

Comment: Thank you both for commenting. Yes it should be Office Open XML, I edited the question accordingly. I get that different `.docx` files will probably not look the same on all devices. But afaik it was the goal to find a standard. I'm still uncertain how in Word for example, the different fonts and formatting are displayed as text while I'm writing a document. Printer drivers are probably called once I want to print my document.